# Sharepoint 2007 dataview sorting ID as though it was text!

Tags: sorting

I have a joined data source that I'm displaying in a dataview, when I add a sort on ID of ascending or descending it seems to treat it as text and not a number.

For example these are the SP generated ID numbers with no sort manually applied in SPD:

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21

With a manual ascending sort in SPD added it becomes this:

1
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
2
20
21
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

It's as though it's sorting by the first character in a number and not the whole number.

I'm pulling my hair out on this. What's even more irritating is that I did virtually the same thing on another joined view a week ago and it worked perfectly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!